# How powerful are the Douwd compared to the Q Continuum?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In TNG episode *The Survivors*, we meet a member of the Douwd race. This alien, and assuming his entire race, has the ability to manipulate matter to create illusions or constructs capable of crippling the Enterprise, create perfect representations of individuals and even commit galaxy-wide genocide of a hostile species. Is the power of the Dowd any different from the power of an individual of the Q Continuum? They seem to be able to do the same manner of things: create spheres of reality where different rules exist, manipulate matter, create illusory individuals, etc.

Are there any instances of their species interacting?

Answer (score 3):

Canonically, no. They've had no interaction depicted on screen, and I can find no evidence they've met in literature or games.

From the little we saw, the Douwd's powers, while vast, were shown to be limited to what the Q could accomplish. For example, Uxbridge had to resort to playing a music box tune in his head to conceal his mind from Deanna, which is what made her ill. But in the case of Q, she could sense his "powerful mind" in one episode, and not in others. Suggesting Q could control when he was sensed.

In addition, Q had total mastery over space, time and reality. While Uxbridge stated his species were pacifists and his powers couldn't be used offensively, he did try to trick the Husnock from attacking his colony, which didn't work. Whereas Q's illusions were so convincing, it was impossible to distinguish them from reality and the crew always had to just ride things out.

So while one could speculate the Douwd just had more rules that prevented them from flexing their powers as broadly as the Q, the one instance we see them in suggests their abilities were limited by comparison.